# Edit Cloudformation template of AWS amplify manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm just new to amplify, but have a good understanding for cloudformation. I used the `amplify add authentication` command and configured the cognito service. However, now I want to add some things to my like lambda triggers in cognito. It is ok to add them to the existence template?

Comment: Have you looked at the following: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/override/ ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I just switched to creating my infrastructure with Cloudformation and only use Amplify JS components.